# setting colour for button text in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicolor

```
UIButton *ConnexionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[ConnexionButton setTitle:@"" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];        
[ConnexionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ConnexionAction) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];

UIImage *NewImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"connectionbtnIcon"];
[ConnexionButton setBackgroundImage:NewImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ConnexionButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[TopView addSubview:ConnexionButton];

[ConnexionButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Connexion", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ConnexionButton.titleLabel setFont:PANTON_SEMIBOLD(15)];
[ConnexionButton.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[TopView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[ConnexionButton]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[TopView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ConnexionButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:TopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:90]];

NSLayoutConstraint *ConnexionButtonHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ConnexionButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:35.0];
[TopView addConstraint:ConnexionButtonHeightConstraint]
```

Comment: am not able to st colour for the button it always shows blue colour which is logo colour...whats the problem quick...

Comment: Where did you set the textColor of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton *ConnexionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Replace this line....

```
UIButton *ConnexionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
ConnexionButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);


[ConnexionButton setTitle:@""
                 forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
[ConnexionButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(ConnexionAction)
          forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIImage *NewImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"connectionbtnIcon"];
[ConnexionButton setBackgroundImage:NewImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ConnexionButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[TopView addSubview:ConnexionButton];
[ConnexionButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Connexion", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ConnexionButton.titleLabel setFont:PANTON_SEMIBOLD(15)];
    [ConnexionButton.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[TopView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[ConnexionButton]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[TopView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ConnexionButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:TopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:90]]; NSLayoutConstraint *ConnexionButtonHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ConnexionButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:35.0];
[TopView addConstraint:ConnexionButtonHeightConstraint];
```

Set color...
You can use

> -[UIButton setTitleColor:forState:]

to do this.

```
[ConnexionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
UIButton *ConnexionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Add

```
UIButton *ConnexionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[ConnexionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ConnexionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0/256.0 green:150.0/256.0 blue:150.0/256.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```